# Finding Common Lines Between 6 Files

Tags: text-processing

I have 6 .txt files on a Linux machine and each file has about 1700 lines. I want to see the lines that are common in 6 of these 6 files, and then the common ones in only 5 of 6, only 4 of 6, only 3 of 6, and the last in only 2 of 6 respectively. I tried to use the following code:

```
comm -12 2.txt 3.txt | comm -12 - 4.txt | comm -12 - 5.txt | comm -12 - 6.txt | comm -12 - 7.txt
```

But I noticed that the result is incomplete and incompatible. And then I did some research and tried the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { lines[$0]=1; next } $0 in lines' 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt
```

But that didn't work either.

I'm new to Ubuntu so I know only very basic things. I will be thankful if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** At @terdon's suggestion, I also tried the following code:

`sort file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 | uniq -c`

And it gave me an output like this:

```
3 VAL455-Main VAL451-Main 
1 VAL455-Main VAL451-Main 
3 VAL463-Main ALA459-Main 
1 VAL463-Main ALA459-Main 
3 VAL468-Main LEU466-Main 
1 VAL468-Main LEU466-Main 
3 VAL468-Main LYS464-Main
```

Let's look at "VAL468-Main LEU466-Main". As you can see, there are two different results in the output. It says that this line exists in both 3 files and only in 1 file. However, this line presents in all the files.

So we still haven't found a solution.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to @FelixJN, we found the source of the problem. If you have a similar one, you can check his answer. :)

Comment: The line does not exist in the other files, otherwise it would have been shown. You either have non-printing characters or just whitespace after the end of the line. Try `sort file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 | uniq -c | sed 's/^/:/; s/$/:/'` and add the output. I bet you'll see some lines have an extra space. Another possibility is that these are files that come from Windows, so you have `\r` in there and that if eating some characters in your terminal.

Comment: Also try this: `grep 'VAL468-Main.*LEU466-Main' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 | sort -u | od -c` that will show all _distinct_ lines with that pattern and show hidden characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` you could do the following:

```
#skip if multiple appearance in one file
{if ( seenin[$0] ~ FILENAME ) {next}}
#add filename to list of files the line has been seen in, increase seen counter
{seenin[$0]=seenin[$0]" "FILENAME ; nseen[$0]++}

#print
END {for (line in nseen) { if (nseen[line]>1) {
   printf "%s \"%s\" %s %d %s %s\n",
     "line",line,"seen in",nseen[line],"files:",seenin[line]} } }
```

Limitation: memory, as all lines are saved in RAM.

If you want to sort by number of occurrences, the print command would have to be adapted accordingly, e.g. sort by values of `nseen`. With `gawk` this is simple: in the `END` block add this before the `for`-loop:

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
```

Input files:

```
$ cat file1
a
a
b
b
c
d
e

$ cat file2
c
c
x
z
e
y
z
f

$ cat file3
f
i
a
c
z
i
k
```

output (with `gawk` feature of array traversal via `PROCINFO`)

```
$awk -f compare_lines_multifiles.awk file1 file2 file3
line "c" seen in 3 files:  file1 file2 file3
line "z" seen in 2 files:  file2 file3
line "a" seen in 2 files:  file1 file3
line "e" seen in 2 files:  file1 file2
line "f" seen in 2 files:  file2 file3
```

---

EDIT:

The files you provide have MSDOS format. Either convert them via

```
 dos2unix file1.txt file2.txt ....
```

or adjust the record separator in `awk`. As first entry in the code add this:

```
 BEGIN { RS="\r\n" }
```

---

EDIT 2: Your files have irregular separators. The problem is, that `a<tab>b` and `a<tab>b<tab>` are treated as different lines, while you may assume them to be the same.

For your very special case with two fields of interest per files, you would rather want to compare the content of these two fields, rather than full lines. Also taking MSDOS-format into account:

```
BEGIN { RS="\r\n" }
#skip if multiple appearance in one file
{if ( seenin[$1"\t"$2] ~ FILENAME ) {next}}
#add filename to list of files the line has been seen in, increase seen counter
{seenin[$1"\t"$2]=seenin[$1"\t"$2]" "FILENAME ; nseen[$1"\t"$2]++}

#print
END {for (line in nseen) { if (nseen[line]>1) {
   printf "%s \"%s\" %s %d %s %s\n",
     "line",line,"seen in",nseen[line],"files:",seenin[line]} } }
```

Ends up with far more overlaps over all six files. It focuses on the two fields with a tab separator and prints the output of a line as such.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different approach. Just pass them all through `sort` and `uniq -c` to count how many times each line was seen:

```
sort 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt | uniq -c
```

That will print out each line once, but will also print the number of times the line was seen. For example, if I have these three files:

```
$ cat file1 
dog
cat
bird

$ cat file2
fly
bird
moose

$ cat file3
bird
dog
flea
```

I would get this output:

```
$ sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq -c
      3 bird
      1 cat
      2 dog
      1 flea
      1 fly
      1 moose
```

So, if you want to separate the lines by the number of times they were found, you could do something like this to see only the lines that appear in all 3 (or 6, in your case) files:

```
$ sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq -c | awk '$1==3'
  3 bird
$ sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq -c | awk '$1==2'
      2 dog
$ sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq -c | awk '$1==1'
      1 cat
      1 flea
      1 fly
      1 moose
```

Comment: I like the approach. Could be expanded to `sort f1 f2 f3 | uniq -c | sort -r | while read line ; do echo -n "$line in: " ; grep -x -m1  "$(cut -d' ' -f 2- <<<"$line")" -l f1 f2 f3 | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo ; done` for having an output like `no. of appearances, line content, list of files` Of course a more lengthy process....

Comment: Thank you very much terdon and @FelixJN. I tried both codes and they gave lines common to 3 files and 2 files, and lines that are only in one of the files, but it doesn't show lines that are common to 4 files, lines that are common to 5 files, and lines that are common to all files. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: And @FelixJN, when I tried your code, my output is also slightly different from yours. It didn't give me which line is common:

line " " seen in 2 files: 3.txt 5.txt
"seen in 3 files: 2.txt 6.txt 7.txt
"seen in 3 files: 2.txt 6.txt 7.txt
"seen in 3 files: 2.txt 6.txt 7.txt

Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DermanBasturk you'll need to add examples of your files in your question to check that. It could be e.g. odd characters. Also: did you select all files as input? The examples use but 3 not 6 files.

Comment: I did actually. :) You can find the files at the following link: https://we.tl/t-hF3E1viETv

Comment: @DermanBasturk don't expect people to download random links like that. Just add a few example lines that reproduce the problem to your question. As long as you run `sort file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 | uniq -c`, you _will_ see all lines and how many files each is present in. If you run this and don't see any examples where the line is present in 4 or 5 files then there are no common lines.

Comment: When I run the code, it gave me an output like this:

      3 VAL455-Main     VAL451-Main
      1 VAL455-Main     VAL451-Main
      3 VAL463-Main     ALA459-Main
      1 VAL463-Main     ALA459-Main
      3 VAL468-Main     LEU466-Main
      1 VAL468-Main     LEU466-Main
      3 VAL468-Main     LYS464-Main

Let's look at "VAL468-Main LEU466-Main". As you can see, there are two different results in the output. It says that this line exists in both 3 files and only in 1 file. However, this line presents in all the files.

Comment: @DermanBasturk pelase add this to your question. Include this specific example and the command you ran. I bet you will find that some lines have spaces or other invisible characters so they are not identical.

Comment: @DermanBasturk if you want, you can come to [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) (our chatroom) and ping me there so we can debug it.

Comment: @DermanBasturk I took a look at the files: they are in MSDOS formatting, so the newlines are a problem. Convert them or adjust handling otherwise. E.g. see my updated answer on `awk`.

Comment: @DermanBasturk Please be careful, though: Your files have a lot of tabs. So `a<tab>b` is different from `a<tab>b<tab>`. See next update.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is the right approach:

```
comm -12 2.txt 3.txt | comm -12 - 4.txt | comm -12 - 5.txt | comm -12 - 6.txt | comm -12 - 7.txt
```

This does the job as a join in parallel as a stream.  In principle you could process files with millions of lines that way.

The problem you had with **comm**(1) appears to have been caused by problems in the input, namely whitespace and line endings.  If you clean those up first, you may find your original approach is both fast and convenient.

Here's an example to prove the point. Find numbers divisible by sets of prime numbers:

```
$ for D in 2 3 5 7 11 13 
> do seq 1 1000 | 
> awk -v D=$D '$0 % D == 0 { print $0 }' | 
> sort > $D
> done

$ comm -12 2 3 | comm -12 - 5 | comm -12 - 7 
210
420
630
840
```

There are, it turns out, no numbers between 1 and 1000 divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
# spits a random three char (a..e)
# string each time it's called
rx() {
  < /dev/urandom \
  tr -cd 'a-e'   |
  fold -w3       |
  head -n 1      \
  ;
}

# modify this section
numFiles=6
numLines=70
commIn=5

# generate random files
for j in $(seq "$numFiles"); do
  for i in $(seq "$numLines"); do
    rx
  done > $j.txt
done

# uniquify each file
# then sort the combined pool
# count n tabulate uniques from this pool
for i in $(seq "$numFiles"); do
  sort -u < "$i.txt"
done                  |
sort | uniq -c        |
sort -b -k1,1nr -k2,2 |
awk -v n="$commIn" '$1+0==n'   ;
```

**Result of this run:**

```
      5 acc
      5 bcd
      5 dac
      5 eea
```